# How to implement wifi chat between android to IOS

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, wifi, android-wifi

is it possible chat `android` to `IOS` using wifi in same network?
if yes,give sample code available for the same. I previously checked for bluetooth chat but it is not possible so now I look on wifi chat help please.

Comment: Create a messaging protocol that both parties can understand. Maybe on Assembler level. Shouldn't be too hard if you just want messaging.

Comment: @freshking thanks for the replay. do you have any sample code for refer

Answer (score 0):

Alljoyn is c++ based library to build up bus connection for two or more devices. You can build up multiplayer game, chat messaging . - https://www.alljoyn.org/

If you would like to make it global ( I mean TCPIP based which i used Node.js is suitable for your project )

You do not get in to deep level. Node.js is here for help developers to build http level socket stream . I builded my own app android and ios with using Node.js client. And server part socket.io library will be handle messaging tail and also with  database driver